# timestamp issue while loading data to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have csv file in which I have a timestamp column in the format below:

```
starttime
--------
2018-01-01 12:00
2018-01-01 12:30
2018-01-01 12:45
2018-01-01 12:15
```

When I load the data into a table using `psql`, it is loaded with the following format:

```
staattime
----------
2018-01-01 12:00:00
2018-01-01 12:00:30
2018-01-01 12:00:45
2018-01-01 12:00:15
```

Ideally it should use the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format, but instead it loads the values as `yyyy-MM-ss hh:ss:mm`

PSQL command : \copy tablename from 'D:/filename.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';

file sample data :

```
EKEY    DKEY    FKEY  SEKEY TZKEY DATEKEY STIME
0       1032    4265    72  9863    23  2017-01-01 09:30
0       1032    4265    72  9863    23  2017-01-01 09:30
0       1032    4265    72  9863    26  2017-01-01 11:00
0       1032    4265    72  9863    27  2017-01-01 11:30
0       570     3785    73  9863    2   2017-01-01 06:00
0       336     3785    73  9863    2   2017-01-01 06:00
0       570     3785    73  9863    2   2017-01-01 06:00
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [edit] your question and add the code you use to load the data. Where and how do you specify that format mask? The `to_timestamp()` and `to_char()` methods use `MI` for minutes and `MM` for month. `mm` and `MM` are the same thing for those functions

Comment: Hi Rajesh, do you using COPY command in psql? Could you please add full line of COPY command and a few line from csv file.

Comment: \copy tablename from 'D:/filename.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';

Comment: Any idea please why its happening...

Comment: you can't edit your csv to simply write the ss ?

Comment: File size is : 80 GB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: edited the question with sample code and copy command